# Unable to cast a HashMap<String,String> to a Interface extending Map<String,String>

Tags: java, generics, dictionary, hashmap, extends

This is probably a simple misunderstanding on my part.

Have a simple interface:

```
public interface IParams extends Map<String,String> {
}
```

Then I try to use:

```
IParams params = (IParams) new HashMap<String,String>();
```

Passes syntax and compile but at runtime i get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.foobar.IParams
```

Any insight into where my misunderstanding of generics is in this case?

Comment: You are not misunderstanding generics, you are misunderstanding inheritance.

Comment: Any reason to extend Map? Are you overriding any methods?

Comment: The intention is to create an interface which hides the generics, and also to hold (not shown in the example) map key string definitions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`HashMap` does not implement your interface `IParams`, so you cannot cast a `HashMap` to an `IParams`. This doesn't have anything to do with generics.

`IParams` and `HashMap` are "siblings", in the sense that both implement or extend `Map`. But that doesn't mean you can treat a `HashMap` as if it is an `IParams`. Suppose that you would add a method to your `IParams` interface.

```
public interface IParams extends Map<String, String> {
    void someMethod();
}
```

Ofcourse, `someMethod` doesn't exist in `HashMap`. If casting a `HashMap` to `IParams` would work, what would you expect to happen if you'd attempt to call the method?

```
IParams params = (IParams) new HashMap<String,String>();

// What's supposed to happen here? HashMap doesn't have someMethod.
params.someMethod();
```

With regard to your comment:

> The intention is to create an interface which hides the generics, and also to hold (not shown in the example) map key string definitions

What you could do is create a class that implements `IParams` and extends `HashMap`:

```
public class Params extends HashMap<String, String> implements IParams {
    // ...
}

IParams params = new Params();
```

Comment: Fantastic explanation, I wasn't thinking in terms of siblings. I was trying too hard to use the HashMap implementation directly and your suggestion of creating a quick concrete class looks pretty reasonable. Thanks Jesper.

Answer (score 3):

`HashMap` implemented `Map` interface but not implemented your Interface `IParams` even though you interface derived from `Map`, you can not cast it to `IParams` as it is not a type of `IParams`